# android java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while calling googlemap.getCameraPostion in StrictMode

Tags: java, android

Sometimes when i try to call getCameraPosition on my google map i am presented with the following exception:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: java.lang.String[] of length 1073741824 would overflow
at android.os.Parcel.readStringArray(Parcel.java:1798)
at android.os.StrictMode$ViolationInfo.<init>(StrictMode.java:2200)
at android.os.StrictMode.readAndHandleBinderCallViolations(StrictMode.java:1738)
at android.os.Parcel.readExceptionCode(Parcel.java:1527)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1496)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IGoogleMapDelegate$zza$zza.getCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.getCameraPosition(Unknown Source)
at com.myexample.fakegps.MainActivity$9.onCameraChange(MainActivity.java:1110)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap$7.onCameraChange(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzf$zza.onTransact(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:380)
at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IOnCameraChangeListener$Stub$Proxy.onCameraChange(IOnCameraChangeListener.java:93)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.a.a(Unknown Source)
at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.api.a$1.run(Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I know its because StrictMode is enabled but when i convert my app into a system app the StrictMode gets enabled and i get this error (running the app as normal app runs fine).

I added the following code to try disable the StrictMode if my users moves my app to system apps:

```
private static void disableStrictMode() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        doDisableStrictMode();
    }

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16) {
        //restore strict mode after onCreate() returns.
        new Handler().postAtFrontOfQueue(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                doDisableStrictMode();
            }
        });
    }
}

private static void doDisableStrictMode() {
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder builder = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder(StrictMode.getThreadPolicy());
    builder.permitAll();
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = builder.build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
        StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder builder2 = new StrictMode.VmPolicy.Builder(StrictMode.getVmPolicy());
        builder2.detectAll();
        builder2.penaltyLog();
        StrictMode.VmPolicy policy2 = builder2.build();
        StrictMode.setVmPolicy(policy2);
    }
}
```

I call this code at the end of onCreate but it doesn´t work and i still get the exception, any ideas?

Comment: If your `SDK` is >=16 you call `doDisableStrictMode` twice - once from the first condition (>=9) and once from the second one. Is that what you meant to do?

Comment: Well you got a good point i should edit the code but i doubt that will solve the problem. I will let you know